# Android show timepicker after datepicker fragment dialog

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

i am using the reference date and time picker dialog from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)
how can i call the time picker after the datepicker dialog?
Because if i put this line 
`showTimePickerDialog(v);` 
into `dateSet` it says non static...

the calling:

```
showDatePickerDialog(v);
showTimePickerDialog(v);
```

Code:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfDay) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    hour = hourOfDay;
    minute = minuteOfDay;
    // Log.e("Idő","" + hourOfDay +" : " + minute);
}
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yearPP = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthPP = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dayPP = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yearPP, monthPP, dayPP);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearP, int monthP, int dayP) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    year = yearP;
    month = monthP+1;
    day = dayP;         

}
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Comment: Not enough detail to answer the question. Show your code.

Comment: What do you mean it says non-static? That you get an error for calling non-static methods from a static class?